# Sports photography lens for m50

Tags: canon, image-quality, lens-mount, lens-adapter, sports

I have a canon eos m50, I need to shoot indoor wrestling photos from a distance.  I will also shoot high school football from the stands.  I want the least expensive options that will still give me a clear image.  I don't even know how to use my camera yet so I def need help on choosing a lens or a lens and converter.  Please help me!

Comment: For sports, especially from a distance, you need a long focal length. For indoor or low-light conditions, as well as for allowing fast shutter speeds to stop motion, you need a large aperture lens. Of course you want high lens/image quality too. You don't mention a budget (and indeed, specific product recommendations are not allowed on this site), but these kinds of lenses simply don't come cheap. Consider buying second-hand, renting, or just biting the bullet and buying a good, expensive lens - you can always re-sell it later if you want.

Comment: There are already questions on this site that will help you. For example... [What Canon lens would be good for shooting high school/college sports?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/96252) | [Is a Canon T4i with 75-300mm EF lens sufficient for shooting night time football?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/82263) | [Are there any cheap, fast lenses capable of highschool sports photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/73672)